# Separating AngularJs and Django into individual Apps?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, django, web-framework, angularjs

I am building a web application using AngularJs and our web server is built in Python Django Rest Framework.

I would like to have the two projects separated and not coupled.

In my current setup the client side web application is served as a NodeJs application while the Node server is being used only as a proxy server to the Django web server APIs.

This setup works, but it doesn't feel right to use NodeJs when all the logic is in the Django server. Also, some of the features we have involve file upload and this makes it even smellier when I upload a file to the node server and then resend it to the Django server.

What are your thoughts on using NodeJs only as a static file server that proxies the requests to different servers, and what other options use cases are there to connect an AngularJs application that is being served as a stand alone app (maybe by NginX) to a Django web server (CORS issues).

Comment: I am in the same situation, I still don't know how to proceed.

Comment: (world)  <-> [balancer|reverse-proxy:nginx] -> [backend]. AngularJS is just static content accessible from nginx. Since backend and static content are served from the same context (domain) there should not be problems with CORS.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the Front-end and Back-end application, actually that's good practice from my view. But you can serve both application in single ip address and different port nos in Apache/Nginx. The server will do static file serve and caching. Cors you can do by Django. You don't need one more server to render the templates.